# java fx: combining texts and images(icons) in a sentence(Label)

Tags: java, javafx

Is it possible to embed an image within a label in between 2 words using Javafx. 
I know its possible to add image at the left, right and middle. 
Is it possible to embed within words? If not is there any other way to do it?

For Example I will have a page where I display the message:

Please select the flowers button (flowers image here) to go to flowers section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [TextFlow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html) for that.

Like this:

```
Text text1 = new Text("word 1");
Text text2 = new Text("word 2");
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(
    new Image(getClass().getResource("smile.png").toExternalForm())
);
TextFlow textFlow = new TextFlow(text1, imageView, text2);
```